# facing error while installing jdk11 using chocolatey

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, chocolatey

i am trying to install jdk11 using chocolatey using below command but facing error

command used to install jdk: choco install jdk11

error:[Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8y4G.png)